# Generating server requests and saving results from server using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to AJAX, I want to send AJAX requests to server in a loop and then showing responses from server. The scenario is on client page I have an array of tables which I want to send one by one, the server receives the table name, processes, and then sends response. On client side I want to show responses as they arrive.e.g.

```
Table 1 processed
Table 2 processed
Table 3 processed
COMPLETED
```

You can have an idea from the following chunk of code what I am trying
    document.getElementById('btnReport').style.display='none';
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableArray.length; i++) 
{
http.open("GET","ServerPage.php?t="+tableArray[i], true);
http.send();
http.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
  {
    eLoader.hide();
    document.getElementById('txtResult').innerHTML += http.responseText;
    document.getElementById('btnReport').style.display='';

  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since you are very new to JavaScript, I would suggest you to use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), which makes the coding easier. It is also JavaScript, but just adds some predefined functions for ease of use.

Now to your question, there is a method in jQuery called [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Using that and `timers` you can achieve what you want.

Typically, you want the requests to start when the page loads. Put the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.load").click(function(){
        $("#result").load("phpPage");
    });
});
```

Here I have used a function called [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), that loads a URL to the element, `<div id="result"></div>`. You can replace it with your particular element.

Comment: Actually I want to run this on button click and saving the responses in a <div> as they arrive. I try using your suggestions.

Comment: I updated it in my question kindly guide now, i think now its more clear

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery`:

```
$(function(){
    $(someButtonElement).on('click', function(){
        var tableArrayLen = tableDataArray.length, i = 0;
        (function sendRequest(i){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'your URL here',
                data: tableDataArray[i],
                success: function(d){
                    $(someResultDiv).append(d);
                    if(i < tableArrayLen) {
                        i++;
                        sendRequest(i);
                    }
                }
            });
        }();
    });

});
```